# Express in terms of Euler integrals

Tags: integration, special-functions

Express in terms of Euler integrals:
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{m-1}}{(1+x)^n} dx
$$

Comment: Please do not use random tags. I put appropriate ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ t=\frac{1}{1+x} $

\begin{align}
 I&=\int_0^1 t^{n-m-1}(1-t)^{m-1} \,dt \\
&=B(n-m,m) \\
&=\frac{\Gamma(n-m) \Gamma(m)}{\Gamma(n)}
\end{align}